# Why is semicolon expected and what does it mean that implicitly-typed local variables must be initialized?

Tags: c#

I get two errors and I have no clue where the error is. Can anyone please help me resolve this issue?

1. ; expected
2. Error       Implicitly-typed local variables must be
   initialized ComputerPlayer.cs   103

Tried searching for ";", but I don't see nothing in the code that is missing.

```
public override bool CheckForHit(Cell guessedCell) // Line 101
{                                                  // Line 102
    var wasHit base.CheckForHit(guessedCell);      // Line 103
}                                                  // Line 104
```

Answer (score 6):

Both errors are related. Watch closely the line 103:

```
var wasHit base.CheckForHit(guessedCell);
```

What was your intention? I imagine you were assigning the result of `CheckForHit` to `wasHit`, but there is no `=` sign anywhere.

Also, [as noted by Mathew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995197/c-sharp-executiong-error/23995251#comment36977740_23995251), there is no `return` in this method, so it won't compile even with `=` added to it.

You may rewrite it as:

```
public override bool CheckForHit(Cell guessedCell)
{
    var wasHit = base.CheckForHit(guessedCell);

    // Additional code goes here.

    return wasHit;
}
```

If there is no additional code, consider simply removing the method, since all it does is to call the base method it overrides.

Comment: and missing `return`.